# Realm deleteAllFromRealm with Nested Objects

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I have a master object with its nested objects those all extends from RealmObject.
I store all nested objects before work with master object.

After deleted a Master Object with these nested objects, i noticed that nested objects are still stored but could not selected with their primary key via  'equalTo()' method.

I filter nObject2 with

```
realm.where(nObject2.class).equalTo("nObject1.Oid",givenOid).findAll()
```

as RealmResults on user selection. If any mObject deleted not yet, Results were correct. But if a mObject deleted, related nObject2 not listed in results with given `nObject1.Oid` next time.

i stored all these objects via `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` or `insertOrUpdate()` and nothing changed and deleted all via mObject `RealmResults.deleteAllFromRealm()`

Nested Object1;

```
 public class nObject1 extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

            private Date LastModifiedOn;
            private String LastModifiedBy;
            private Date CreatedOn;
            private String CreatedBy;
            @PrimaryKey
            private String Oid;

    //getters and setters
    }
```

Nested Object2;

```
public class nObject2 extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
        private nObject1 nObject1;   
        private Date LastModifiedOn;
        private String LastModifiedBy;
        private Date CreatedOn;
        private String CreatedBy;
        @PrimaryKey
        private String Oid;

//getters and setters
}
```

and Master Object;

```
public class mObject extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
        private nObject1 nObject1; 
        private nObject2 nObject2; 
        private Date LastModifiedOn;
        private String LastModifiedBy;
        private Date CreatedOn;
        private String CreatedBy;
        @PrimaryKey
        private String Oid;

//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"nObject1.Oid"` creates a link query across `nObject2`'s `nObject1` field. It means that you are looking for the `Oid` of `nObject1`.

If `nObject1` with `Oid` is deleted, then obviously it won't be found.

If you are trying to find `nObject2` with its own `Oid`, then you should just use `.equalTo("Oid"`.

If you are trying to find `nObject2` with `nObject1`'s `Oid` even if `nObject1` is separately deleted, then also store that oid as part of `nObject2` in its schema, for example `@Index private String nObject1Oid` and query based on that.

Comment: thank you.
I never delete nObject1 or nObject2. I delete only masterObject.
Before I delete master object i can find nObject2 with nObject1.Oid but after masterObject deleted I can't find. At this delete point i want to avoid manipulate related nested objects in realm.
The last paragraph you wrote about Indexing nObject1Oid as string was a solution, but my project does not include only 3 objetcs and there are much deeper classes with nested objects. 
Probably i have a misconception about realm and my goal is fix it.

Comment: How exactly do you delete `mObject`?

Comment: `if (!baseRealm.isInTransaction())
        {
            baseRealm.beginTransaction();
        }  
        baseRealm.where(mObject.class).notEqualTo("TransactionState.isSynchronized",false).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();   

baseRealm.commitTransaction();`

Comment: ....that's it? That shouldn't invalidate links between `object1` and `object2`. O_o what Realm version is this?

Comment: version is 3.7.0;
my whole method is like:  
if (!baseRealm.isInTransaction())
        {
            baseRealm.beginTransaction();
        }
        baseRealm.where(mObject.class).notEqualTo("TransactionState.isSynchronized",false).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            mObject obj = list.get(i);

            baseRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj);
        }  
        baseRealm.commitTransaction();